# merge rows in one column based on second column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have Two columns in dataframe. one is names and other is Pos.

I want to modify this dataframe by applying a loop on Pos Column. Start from B-PER value and  Concatenate names in names column until Value in Pos column becomes B-PER again and then repeat

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['names'] = ['John', 'Smith', 'Adam', 'Marry', 'Leo', 'Lauana']
df['POS'] = ['B-PER', 'I-PER', 'I-PER', 'B-PER', 'I-PER', 'B-PH']

df.groupby(df['POS'].eq('B-PER').cumsum()).agg({'names': '+'.join, 'POS': '+'.join})

    names             POS   
1   John+Smith+Adam B-PER+I-PER+I-PER
2   Marry+Leo       B-PER+I-PER
3   Lauana          B-PH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pseudo column by checking equality for B-PER in the POS column and running a cumsum over the boolean mask. Later groupby over this new column and do required aggregations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['names'] = ['John', 'Smith', 'Adam', 'Marry', 'Leo']
df['POS'] = ['B-PER', 'I-PER', 'I-PER', 'B-PER', 'I-PER']

df.groupby(df['POS'].eq("B-PER").cumsum()).agg({'names': '+'.join, 'POS': '+'.join})

    names             POS
POS     
1   John+Smith+Adam B-PER+I-PER+I-PER
2   Marry+Leo       B-PER+I-PER
```

As per the comment (which was not clear),

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['names'] = ['John', 'Smith', 'Adam', 'Marry', 'Leo', "Launa"]
df['POS'] = ['B-PER', 'I-PER', 'I-PER', 'B-PER', 'I-PER', "B-PH"]

df.groupby((df['POS'].eq("B-PER") | df['POS'].eq("B-PH")).cumsum(), as_index=False).agg({'names': '+'.join, 'POS': '+'.join})



            names   POS
0   John+Smith+Adam B-PER+I-PER+I-PER
1   Marry+Leo       B-PER+I-PER
2   Launa           B-PH
```

Comment: Acutually i forgot to mention one thing in dataframe that there is one more value in Pos column other than B-PER and I-PER and that is B-PH and this row should not be merged with other rows. how it will be possible

     names           POS
    POS  
    1 John+Smith+Adam B-PER+I-PER+I-PER
    2 Marry+Leo     B-PER+I-PER
    3   Lauana          B-PH

how will i get this output?

Comment: update your Q please. Add dataframes as text not images